# Finding the intersection of a paraboloid and an ellipse in 3d space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, parametrization

We're given the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ and the ellipsoid $4x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 9$, and we need to parameterize the curve at which they intersect.

I've tried parameterizing this trigonometrically, but it just never works. Substituting one equation into another seemed circular.

Comment: As per [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), you should show your steps even if they don't lead you anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting directly gives $3x^2 + z + z^2 = 9$, and completing the square, $3x^2 + (z + 1/2)^2 = 37/4$, so $x = \frac{\sqrt{37/4} \cos t}{\sqrt3}; z = \sqrt{37/4} \sin t - 1/2$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: $y = \pm\sqrt{z - x^2}$, substituting everything with respect to $t$.